# Treeview checkbox act as radiobutton

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, kendo-ui, radio-button, treeview

Sample diagram:

[image]

I want this specific group of nodes to act as radiobutton(only 1 should be checked). I know I can handle this by hard coding conditions but I want to make it expandable in the future(adding more checkbox) by changing its json column 'Group'.

sample data:

```
                      [
                        { id:"1", text: "Items", expanded: true, List: [
                            { id:"2",text: "book" ,group: 1},//group for radiobutton actions
                            { id:"3",text: "chair",group: 1 },
                            { id:"4",text: "table",group: 1 },
                            { id:"5",text: "mat", group: 0 },
                            { id:"6",text: "decor", group: 0}
                        ] }
                      ]
```

I found this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5EuS/2112/) exmaple about group attribute for references.

Comment: You will have to code it anyway, the question is how you make it reusable. I suggest to create a *wrapper* for your treeview in case you have any other customizations in the widget made by yourself; or just create a function to handle it, so you can call it whenever you need.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I think i can use node.find by 'group: 1' then set it to false. Is that possible?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Can you please put the snippet of your process? I need to create at least a functional code for now then the shortened later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best(I think) way to do this:

**1. Declare array of IDs w/c you want to grouped by:**

```
var group = ["2","3","4"]; //in my example above
```

**2. In the `check` event:**

```
 if (group.indexOf(dataItem.ID) > -1) { //if the ID you clicked exists in the group
       group.splice(group.indexOf(dataItem.ID), 1); //remove the ID from the group
       for (var i = 0, j = treeview.length; i < j; i++) {
           for (var x = 0, y = treeview[i].List.length; x < y; x++) {
               if (group.indexOf(treeview[i].List[x].ID) > -1) { 
                   treeview[i].List[x].set("checked", false); //uncheck the members of the group
               }
           }
       }
   }
```